# Is Krishna answering the question "who is the better wielder of weapons" between Arjuna and Rama in BG 10.31?

Tags: rama, arjuna, weapon

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/10/verse/31

पवन: पवतामस्मि राम: शस्त्रभृतामहम् | झषाणां मकरश्चास्मि स्रोतसामस्मि जाह्नवी || 31||

BG 10.31: Amongst purifiers, I am the wind, and **amongst wielders of weapons, I am Lord Ram.** Of water creatures, I am the crocodile, and of flowing rivers, I am the Ganges.

The greatest archer of the Mahabharata, Arjuna (said to be Nara of the Nara-Narayana pair) was right next to him, but he chose Rama as the best wielder of weapons.

Arjuna's track record is clearly better - he fought the greatest of his time - Bhishma,Drona,Karna and either won or fought to a draw.  Put his life on the line to kill Jayadratha by sunset and won.  Rama didn't fight the greatest warrior of his time Indrajit and actually Ravana was hardly a a match for him.

Comment: "The greatest archer **of the Mahabharata**" - even this is debatable, cos the invincible Bhishma was right across the field. and Krishna is talking about greatest of all time, not just Mahabharat

Comment: Do you doubt the power of Lord ram ?